# Simple, intuitive and (hopefully) safe EventDispatcher

Tags: c++, game, c++14, event-handling, template-meta-programming

For my own game engine I need an event system. I tried to avoid the single-huge-enum-approach for minimizing compile times.

The `BasicEventListener` is the (obviously) base class of the `EventListener` and is needed for storing EventListeners in a list:

```
class BaseEventListener {
    friend class EventDispatcher;
    std::map<EventId, EventDispatcher&> dispatchers;
public:
    virtual ~BaseEventListener() {
        for (auto& pair : dispatchers)
             pair.second.listeners[pair.first].erase(this);
    }
};
```

The Destructor of `BaseEventListener` ensures, that the dispatchers will not try to dispatch an `Event` to an deleted `EventListener`. It will remove `this` from the corresponding `EventDispatcher`.

The `EventListener` itself looks as follow:

```
template <typename Event>
class EventListener : public virtual BaseEventListener {
public:
    virtual void handleEvent(const Event&) = 0;
};
```

The user now is able to inherit from EventListener with

```
class ConcreteEventListener : public EventListener<KeyPressed>, 
                              public EventListener<KeyReleased> {...}
```

Now I'm getting to the Dispatcher:

```
class EventDispatcher final {
    friend class BaseEventListener;
    std::map<EventId, std::set<BaseEventListener*>> listeners;
    std::queue<std::function<void()>> eventQueue;
public:
    // register an EventListener to the Dispatcher
    template <typename Event>
    bool add(EventListener<Event>& listener) {
        EventId eventId = getEventId<Event>();

        if (!listener.dispatchers.try_emplace(eventId, *this).second) return false;
        bool success = listeners[eventId].insert(&listener);
        assert(success); // shouldn't fail

        return true;
    }

    // remove an EventListener from the Dispatcher
    template <typename Event>
    void remove(EventListener<Event>& listener) {
        EventId eventId = getEventId<Event>();

        if (!listener.dispatchers.erase(eventId)) return;
        bool success = listeners[eventId].erase(&listener);
        assert(success); // shouldn't fail
    }

    // (2) Directly dispatch to EventListeners
    template <typename Event, typename... Args>
    void dispatch(Args&&... args) {
        Event ev(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        for (auto& listener : listeners[getEventId<Event>()])
            dynamic_cast<EventListener<Event>*>(listener)->handleEvent(ev);
    }

    // (3) Queue Event for later dispatching
    template <typename Event, typename... Args>
    void queue(Args&&... args) {
        eventQueue.emplace([event{std::make_shared<Event>(std::forward<Args>(args)...)}, this] {
            for (auto& listener : listeners[getEventId<Event>()])
                dynamic_cast<EventListener<Event>*>(listener)->handleEvent(*event);
        });
    }

    // dispatch queued Events
    void tick() {
        while (!eventQueue.empty()) {
            eventQueue.front()();
            eventQueue.pop();
        }
    }

    // clean up EventListeners
    ~EventDispatcher() {
        for (auto& eventListenerSet : listeners)
            for (auto& eventListener : eventListenerSet.second)
                eventListener->dispatchers.erase(eventListenerSet.first);
    }
};
```

Now the questioning :)

- (2), (3): Is this well defined behavior/good practice/clean/performant?
- For a multithreaded engine, I guess all the sections should be mutex locked?

Comment: It may be useful to review Qt's model of threads and event loops.  Essentially, every Qt object "belongs" to a particular thread, and each thread is responsible for delivering events to its own objects.  So the only cross-thread communication (unless explicitly bypassed by the programmer) is when posting events to another thread, and everything else needs no mutex.

Comment: This is indeed a nice approach. I will look into it, thanks!